# Webpack Devserver - Angular2 - allowing extensions

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

so for out app, there is a requirement that all the URLs have .app extension...

so http://domain/news.app
http://domain/article.app?blah=blah

while this works fine on the production (apache) server (actual resolving the extensions) it doesn't work on my webpack dev server... or at least I cannot find any settings to make it work

in my angular app routes for example I have this

```
const appRoutes: Routes  = [
    { path: 'home.app', pathMatch: 'full', component: AppPage},
    { path: 'news.app', pathMatch: 'full', component: AppNews}
];
```

webpack.dev conf

```
output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
},
```

so if I do http://localhost:8080/news.app .... I get

**Cannot GET /news.app**

How to setup the dev server that would allow /news.app ?

Answer (score 1):

```
devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: 'index.html'
    }
  }
```

This will redirect all your call to index.html , and then Angular2 router will take it from there.

The mystery is of course behind the **historyApiFallback** , which will tell webpack to fall back to index.html in any case .

Comment: doesn't seem to work.... will do a bit more testing... is it possible it doesn't work cause the baseurl is not set to "/" ? Will do some investigating and report back

Comment: is it possible cause of 'dist' set in output path?

Comment: I found the setting that made it work historyApiFallback: {disableDotRule: true}, - THANKS

Answer (score 0):

[I found the setting](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) in historyApiFallback .... that solves my problem

```
historyApiFallback: {
    disableDotRule: true
},
```

Thanks to xe4me that pointed me to the right direction